# Why there are so many difference in traditions in hinduism?

Tags: festivals, tradition, calendar

For example, Deepavali is celebrated differently in different parts of India, even though Deepavali is a hindu festival.

One more example, there are different calendars for the hinduism (Chandramana and Souramana). Which results in celebrating the same festival on different days across different regions (Example: Ugadi).

Comment: [Why are there so many Gods in Hinduism?](https://youtu.be/Kg8L4-wv4Vg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from an article by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar:

> ..In Hinduism, there is no one central book, and no one specific
>   culture. Therefore, those who are trying to bring unification are
>   doing injustice to the very structure of Hinduism. Celebrating
>   diversity is in the very DNA of Hinduism; that is the reason why it is
>   most needed today in the whole world. The world is diverse — but all
>   conflicts are about trying to make the world monolithic. Celebration
>   of diversity is the only way to counter extremism...

You can read the full article here:
http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/treasurehunt/diversity-is-in-the-dna-of-hinduism/